# Cesium and KML altitude

Tags: kml, cesium

I have the following KML file which is a cube:

```
</Placemark>
<Style id="3Dobject">
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>7fff5500</color>
        <outline>1</outline>
        <fill>1</fill>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
    <name>Warehouse01</name>
    <description>Warehouse Center：106.97777777 -6.19758333</description>
    <styleUrl>#3Dobject</styleUrl>
    <Polygon>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    106.9772778,-6.19808333,100
                    106.9782778,-6.19808333,100
                    106.9782778,-6.19708333,100
                    106.9772778,-6.19708333,100
                    106.9772778,-6.19808333,100
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

I am trying to make this cube to be drawn 100 meters above the ground, so basically:

[image]

I tried adding an 100 but it always display from the bottom.

I am using CESIUM.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Cesium KML Support Page](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/873), Cesium hasn't supported some `altitudeMode' options yet.

More importantly, the post in link: [How to create 3D boxes within a KML file without ground contact?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154633/how-to-create-3d-boxes-within-a-kml-file-without-ground-contact) says "It's not easy. But somehow you can create a cube in the air" in KML. The link in the post is dead. So I suggest to review the example below. (Source: [Keyhole Markup Language – Hello Cube](https://kgm.zcu.cz/projekty/3DGIS/HelloCube/KML/kml.html))

Briefly, you have to define all surfaces of the cube as in the example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Document> 
 <name>KML Cube Sample - absolute</name> 
 <Folder>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Top</name>
    <Polygon>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>        
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
           13.3761524993111,49.7401011145834,2400
           13.3897280864525,49.7401011145834,2400
           13.3897280864525,49.7492856863423,2400
           13.3761524993111,49.7492856863423,2400
           13.3761524993111,49.7401011145834,2400
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>      
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Side A</name>
    <Polygon>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
           13.3761524993111,49.7401011145834,1400
           13.3897280864525,49.7401011145834,1400
           13.3897280864525,49.7401011145834,2400
           13.3761524993111,49.7401011145834,2400
           13.3761524993111,49.7401011145834,1400           
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>      
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Side B</name>
    <Polygon>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
           13.3897280864525,49.7401011145834,1400
           13.3897280864525,49.7492856863423,1400
           13.3897280864525,49.7492856863423,2400
           13.3897280864525,49.7401011145834,2400
           13.3897280864525,49.7401011145834,1400           
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>      
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Side C</name>
    <Polygon>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
           13.3897280864525,49.7492856863423,1400
           13.3761524993111,49.7492856863423,1400
           13.3761524993111,49.7492856863423,2400
           13.3897280864525,49.7492856863423,2400
           13.3897280864525,49.7492856863423,1400
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>      
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Side D</name>
    <Polygon>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
           13.3761524993111,49.7492856863423,1400
           13.3761524993111,49.7401011145834,1400
           13.3761524993111,49.7401011145834,2400
           13.3761524993111,49.7492856863423,2400
           13.3761524993111,49.7492856863423,1400
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>      
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Bottom</name>
    <Polygon>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>        
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
           13.3761524993111,49.7401011145834,1400
           13.3761524993111,49.7492856863423,1400
           13.3897280864525,49.7492856863423,1400
           13.3897280864525,49.7401011145834,1400
           13.3761524993111,49.7401011145834,1400                  
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>      
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
 </Folder>
</Document>  
</kml>
```

Comment: thank for the reply. I read that page before, they say they support altitudeMode (the normal not gx) with absolute positioning, but yes apparently it's not fully working ? will try your exemple thank you